# ansible ec2 az variable

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-facts

Folks,
  In my .j2 template, I would like to use an ansible variable from each host like so

```
dc_suffix={{ ansible_ec2_placement }}
```

However, the `"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: ERROR! 'ansible_ec2_placement' is undefined"}` error appears.

What is the correct syntax for ansible to fetch the availability zone for a particular instance?  The [ec2_facts docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_facts_module.html) are scarce

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to do this:

```
- name: Gather facts
  action: ec2_facts
  register: ec2_facts
```

Then in the termplate:

```
dc_suffix={{ ec2_facts.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone }}
```

Anything wrong with doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, this looks like the proper way of doing it.  Unfortunately documentation for a lot of facts, etc. are scarce in ansible, in part because there are so many and they're dependant upon your environment and other factors.  I find the best approach is to invoke a task as you did then use the debug task to display the results and use that as a guideline.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simpler than @Cmag's answer, at least for ansible v 1.9:

```
- name: gather ec2 facts
  action: ec2_facts

- name: display AZ
  debug: msg="region is {{ ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone }}"
```

From the shell, you can view all facts set by ec2_facts with the following:

```
echo "localhost ansible_connection=local" >inv
ansible -m ec2_facts localhost -i inv
```

which will print out a large number of variables in json format.